# Set a maximum value for an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, case, max

I am trying to create a score based on the `char_length` of a field. I am using a fraction of the `char_length` returned.

```
 (CASE WHEN (char_length(e.summary)/100) is null THEN +0
  ELSE +(char_length(e.summary)/100) END)
```

I would like to know how to set a maximum return value. Is there a simple function or do I need to do one more `CASE WHEN with if >=10 THEN` ... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify to:

```
LEAST(COALESCE(length(e.summary)/100, 0), 10)
```

- Use [**LEAST**()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-GREATEST-LEAST) to introduce an upper border as @Mark already mentioned.
- Use [**COALESCE**()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) to provide a default for `NULL` values.
- [`length()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-OTHER) does the same as `char_length()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `least` function.

`least(<YOUR CALC HERE>, 10)` limits the maximum value returned to 10.